# Chrome won't install on kali Linux through virtualization

Tags: kali-linux, virtual-machine, chrome, macintosh

I have a MacBook on M1 and using UTM virtualization I installed Kali. While installing Chrome using command: `sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` , I got this error:

```
 google-chrome-stable:amd64 : Depends: libasound2:amd64 (>= 1.0.17) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libatk1.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libatspi2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.9.90) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libcairo2:amd64 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libcups2:amd64 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 but it is not installable or
                                       libcurl3-nss:amd64 but it is not installable or
                                       libcurl4:amd64 but it is not installable or
                                       libcurl3:amd64 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libdbus-1-3:amd64 (>= 1.9.14) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libdrm2:amd64 (>= 2.4.75) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libexpat1:amd64 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libgbm1:amd64 (>= 17.1.0~rc2) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.39.4) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libgtk-3-0:amd64 (>= 3.9.10) but it is not installable or
                                       libgtk-4-1:amd64 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libnspr4:amd64 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libnss3:amd64 (>= 2:3.26) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libvulkan1:amd64 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libx11-6:amd64 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libxcb1:amd64 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libxcomposite1:amd64 (>= 1:0.4.4-1) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libxdamage1:amd64 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libxext6:amd64 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libxfixes3:amd64 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libxkbcommon0:amd64 (>= 0.5.0) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libxrandr2:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a problem with architecture of my machine or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Don't take this the wrong way :-)

The problem is that you're a Linux beginner and Kali really isn't newbie-compatible. It's not a desktop OS, but a security professionals' toolbox. Fixing broken dependencies is a basic skill, which users are expected to have.

This isn't even fixable with usual methods without breaking Kali as [`vulkan` isn't part of Kali since 2019](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/vulkan). A **LOT** of things in Kali are "broken" this way *on purpose* and you're bound to run into similar issues with it.

I'd recommend that you install a regular Debian to learn the basics, and just add the tools you're interested in. Kali has 600+ of them, and nobody uses them all. They're nothing special, but available for any distro; in Debian with just `sudo apt install`.

If you do want to continue with Kali specifially, you should read through the [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/) so you have an understanding what you're dealing with.

Comment: Don’t take this the wrong way :-). Claiming things are broken on purpose is a rather strong statement that should be backed by evidence. `vulkan` was removed from Kali because [it was removed from Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/vulkan). `libvulkan1` is provided by [`vulkan-loader`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/vulkan-loader) and that set of packages [is available in Kali](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/vulkan-loader).

Comment: @StephenKitt LOL yeah :-D With "broken" things I don't mean they;re _broken_, just "not available without going through extra hoops that would be unnecessary with a regular OS designed for desktop usage". Hence quotes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple command whenever a supported package missing with any installation package on debian based system, which Kali is also debian based use

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: @StephenKitt Ok, I hadn't seen that part. Then the main problem likely is trying to install a package from a downloaded `.deb` file that [isn't available](https://pkg.kali.org/search?package_name=google-chrome-stable) in the Kali repos in the first place. However, that would still imply `apt --fix-broken` can't help in this case...

Comment: @AdminBee yes, I agree `--fix-broken` is unlikely to help.

Comment: With kali VM , I am using after installing it by .deb package. By command "sudo dpkg -i package.deb" and then did "sudo apt --fix-broken install" it worked for me.